# To find a positive whole number point on a hyberbola

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, estimation

In a hyperbola of equation $$ x^2 - y^2 = N $$ where $N$ is a product of two unknown odd numbers, say $x$ and $y$ such that $x > \sqrt{N} > y$ and $x \ne 1$ and $y \ne N$ , there will be a point that will have $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates which are whole numbers. Assuming N has only two factors except 1, is there any way one can find this point or estimate its location?

Comment: $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by David C. Ullrich's comment:

Suppose $N=ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are odd integers, and suppose $a\le b$. Then $n=\frac{a+b}{2}$ is an integer, as is $m=b-n$. Thus, we have the point $(n,m)$ on our hyperbola, because $$n^2-m^2=(n-m)(n+m)=ab=N.$$

---

Upon further discussion, I see that the question was really the following: Suppose $N$ is a large odd number, and we wish to determine if it has factors by examining integer points on the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=N$. We are guaranteed to find four integer points, namely $(\frac{N+1}{2},\pm\frac{N-1}{2})$, and $(-\frac{N+1}{2},\pm\frac{N-1}{2})$. If we find any more, then we have found a factorization: $N=(x-y)(x+y)$.

Thus, the OP wants to know whether there is a geometric strategy for finding such points, and can such a strategy be used as a method for factoring large numbers?

As far as I know, the problem of locating such integer points is no different from the problem of factoring $N$. If $N$ is hard to factor, then the points are hard to find. Factoring has been studied extensively, and I don't know the current best results, but if you want to find out more about this, I recommend asking a new question, and including *context* about what problem you're really investigating. Failing to include such context can only lead to confusion.

Comment: Ok but how do I find the values of $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: They are any two numbers whose product is $N$. We are given that $N$ is a product of two odd integers. If nothing else, they could be $1$ and $N$ itself.

Comment: G Tony Jacobs I have just edited the question to answer for  comment

Comment: It doesn’t change anything. Is $N$ somehow impossible to factor? Any pair of factors will do.

Comment: I have made necessary changes to the question

Comment: Well. This is frustrating. Are you really asking how to factor a number?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Yes this is a factoring problem . I am trying different ways of factoring such a number

Comment: Ok, you want to factor a number.... by finding integer points on a hyperbola? It would be helpful if you wrote the question in a way that made your goal clear from the start. If this is a question about a factoring method, why not say so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69742/discussion-between-abishek-shankar-and-g-tony-jacobs).

Comment: @AbishekShankar, I have updated my answer with further comments.

Comment: Thanks @GTonyJacobs , Will do so